# 3-tier database application web client in ASP.Net and the business logic in java

Tags: java, asp.net, n-tier-architecture

I am new in this area and I want to know how could I develop such an application. I already have a developed application in java (the business logic) and I would want to link this with a
web application in ASP.Net (application client). I know that I must use a web service but which type should I use a java web service or a .Net web service.

I dont know how to make this connection between the .net and java, could anyone help me please? Is this possible through the web service? Any action of the user would then be transmitted to the java application...and if this is the case how it is done? Any example or tutorial might be hepfull....

Thank you in advance

Comment: out of interest, why didn't you code the model in .NET?

Comment: I've retagged from JavaME to JavaEE as it hasn't anything connected to mobile edition. Also I think `client` should be removed and `net` or `asp` added. Fix me if I wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a SOAP web service, it doesn't matter whether you use Java or .NET.  The client is exchanging SOAP XML messages over HTTP; the language that the service is written in does not come into play.

Same would be true of REST if you did it properly.